# What is the best term to designate a member of a sodality?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

At first I would have thought that a member of a sodality would be identified as a *sodalite*, but if that usage ever existed, it has been completely erased by the mineral of that name.

I'm looking to mirror a usage where a member of a fraternity is a brother, a member of a sorority is a sister, a member of an initiatory order is an initiate, and so on.

How can I say "Bob is an X" such that X designates Bob as a member of a sodality?

Comment: Bob is a sodalist, though a quick scan gives me that word only twice on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodality_of_Our_Lady)

Comment: I think this has to be General Reference. Personally, I didn't even know the word ***sodality*** before now, but if OP's vocabulary extends that far he can surely look up ***sodalist*** in the dictionary.

Comment: As FumbleFingers noted, the OP can surely look up the answer in the dictionary. In fact, the OP *should* have, as a prerequisite.

Comment: It amazes me how ridiculous these comments are.  I'm looking for a word that documentably *barely exists*, and this is somehow general reference?  Shut the front door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more appropriate word is ***[sodalist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sodalist)***:

> - A member of a sodality.(AHD)

Comment: That sounds more like a believer or promoter in the concept of sodality.

Comment: @Barmar But it's what (some of) the [dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sodality) say is the correct term.

Comment: From OED: **sodalist** *- a member of a Roman Catholic **sodality** or religious fraternity.*

Answer (score 1):

While the venerable OED has an entry for sodalist, for me it's more important to see what word Catholics use.

In the Catholic Encyclopedia the entry for [sodality](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14120a.htm) uses the word *member*, but not *sodalite* or *sodalist*.

So OED notwithstanding, I would just use *member*.

Answer (score 0):

The OED has exactly two references for "sodalist", from 1794 and 1889. To me it sounds a bit too much like "sodomist". Why not stick with "member of a sodality"?